# Can I get only first entry of atom feed?

Tags: feed

[This atom feed](http://resource.ufocatch.com/atom/edinetx/query/E00515) returns 500 entry for each page.

But I just need a first entry to minimize data transfer.
Is there a way to get a first entry?

Or is it impossible unless server side engineer implements the argument for it?